# Scheduling periodic function call in Quart/asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, quart

I need to schedule a periodic function call in python (ie. called every minute), without blocking the event loop (I'm using [Quart](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/) framework with [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)).

Essentially need to submit work onto the event loop, with a timer, so that the webserver keeps serving incoming requests in the meantime and roughly every minute it calls my function.

I tried many ways, for instance:

```
def do_work():
    print("WORK", flush=True)

async def schedule():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print("scheduling")
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    t = loop.call_later(2, do_work)
    print("scheduled")
    

asyncio.run(schedule())
```

But it either never gets executed (like the code above), or it blocks the webserver main event loop. For instance, with the code above I would expect (since it's done within `asyncio.run` and `schedule` awaits timer) that "scheduling" would be printed after (or during) the server setup, but that's not the case, it blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [background task](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/how_to_guides/background_tasks.html) that is [started on startup](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/how_to_guides/startup_shutdown.html),

```py
async def schedule():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await do_work()

@app.before_serving
async def startup():
    app.add_background_task(schedule)
```

which will run `schedule` for the lifetime of the app, being cancelled at shutdown.

Comment: Note: this requires quart 0.16.